# HttpURLConnection сайт требует включение javascript

Tags: javascript, java

Я делал авторизацию на сайте через post запрос, всё получилось, но только после авторизации сайт требует включить JavaScript. Как мне включить или имитировать включение JavaScript ?

Comment: мне кажется что вопрос должен содержать чуть больше конкретики, возможно отрывки листинга. что значит "сайт требует", например.

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin Благодарю за ответ.  После post запроса открывается страница где написано "Идёт вход в аккаунт... Если это сообщение не исчезнет, включите поддержку JavaScript и отключить Расширение Браузера Adblock, NoScript и им подобные". Если заходить через Браузер, то он перезагружаеться несколько раз и всё работает. Вот ссылка на сайт (если надо) http://surfsitmoney.com

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin вы можете мне помочь ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просетьте Accept-header HTTP запроса, должно вылечить.